# how to stop auto calling of click event in JSF

Tags: javascript, java, jsf

I have JSF h:commandButton> called "Export" in GUI like below

```
<h:commandButton id="export" value="Export" onClick="return showExportOverlayWindow(this.form)" styleClass="submit-button" />
```

[image]

when i click on the export button an user prompt will come as below
[image]

Then when i click on "OK" button [note the numbe of user >1000], calling the java layer to export all the users details plus other details as well in excel sheet. approximately 3-4 minutes per 1000 user processing time [image]

Java method as follows

[image]

All looks good until i export < 1000 users. Problem starts for exporting user > 1000 I can observe in logger that java method is called multiple times (number of called times is not constant.  it differs each time ). like below

Exporting......

Exporting......

Exporting......

Can anyone help me why its happening when data increased please? If export data less then 1000 or so only one time the java layer is called

Comment: Several things: 1: Doing these kinds of 'long processing' actions synchronously is bad design. 2: How do you know jsf keeps 'auto-clicking' (= from the client side? The fact that the method is called multiple times could be caused by a reverse proxy re-executing the long processing http call again and again... So debug the client requests. 3:  please post code in text and not images... 4: can you reproduce in a plain java class with just a main and not classes other than those from the jdk? If not, the question is not java-se related. 5: Please create a [mcve] with e.g. a thread-sleep

Comment: Try to check if you are running into exceptions using debug..